# Horizontal Smooth Scroll One Page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been building a horizontal one page site. And for the past two days, I've been trying all kinds of different things with no luck. Finally, I figured out how to make the smooth scroll work. But not entirely.. It slides over slightly, but it does not slide the full section.

Here's the function.

```
    $(function() {
          $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                $('body').animate({
                  scrollLeft: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
              }
            }
          });
        });
```

Full site can be found at levistroop.com/test

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Best,
Levi

Comment: Try setting 'scrollLeft: target.offset().left' instead of top.

Comment: Perfect!! I completely missed that. Thanks so much.

Comment: @GreggDuncan you can set that as the answer for credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting 'scrollLeft: target.offset().left' instead of top

Answer (score 1):

Just a small change:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('body').animate({
          scrollLeft: target.offset().left
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```